# AWS CDK - how does one debug a hanging deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

There are times when I run `cdk deploy` and it will get to creating a ECS service and just hang because I did "something" wrong with my config  --

```
55/57 Currently in progress: MyServiceFA17513E
```

Is there any way to get insight into what the problem is? It seems to take quite long to timeout (hour+?)

Comment: Have you checked ECS service events description?

Comment: Go to CloudFormation console and check out the stack that is creating

Comment: Thanks @Marcin that's what I was looking for. Now I'm able to see,

>service my-service was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance abbb7c1b-... has insufficient memory available

Comment: can you post your configuration? so we can see what you are doing right now and hopefully come up with a solution.

Comment: what base image are you using? You can't use `FROM scratch`

Comment: No problem. Have you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes issue solved. @JonnyRimek I wasn't worried about the configuration necessarily, more the process of how to debug when you run into a situation like this.

Comment: can you layout your solution pls? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: @JonnyRimek in my case I needed to allocate less memory to my containers so they could fit in the ec2 instance (or bump up the ec2 instance size)

Comment: interesting, my issue was caused because I disabled the NATGateway, afaik. I'm 90% sure^^

Comment: you can also add a  ```-v``` to the CLI

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can run your command with the verbose parameter to get more details
`cdk deploy -vv`